# Splitting a text file based on not case sensitive line content

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files, readlines

I have a bunch of text files ('f' in the code below) that I want to split into two new files ('f1' and 'f2' in the code below) based on where a certain phrase shows up in the file ('post' in the code below). But because OCR isn't perfect the phrase is the same across the files but the case sensitivity is not (ie sometimes all the letters are capitalized, sometimes only the first letter of certain words, etc). Can anyone help me tweek my code to make the search term not case sensitive?

Here's what I have:

```
f = open(thefile)
post = "Letters To The Editor"
doIHaveToCopyTheLine = False
ignoreLines = False
for line in f.readlines():
    if not ignoreLines:
        f2.write(line)
    if (post) in line:
        doIHaveToCopyTheLine = True
        ignoreLines = True
    if doIHaveToCopyTheLine:
        f1.write(line)
```

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I've looked everywhere and can't figure out how to both search for a phrase where case doesn't matter *and* have it write the content from the original file into 2 new files based on the location of that phrase. Thanks, from a self-taught coder :-)

Comment: Use `.lower()`? If they're both the same case for the if, case won't matter.

Comment: Hi, use .lower() where? I'm still learning and it's not obvious to me where I would put that in. Thanks.

Comment: @SashaHoffman the second if should be `if post.lower() in line.lower():`, this will give to *new* strings (the other strings will not be affected) where all the letters are lower

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much! You both just saved me hours of headaches.